# Kafka consumer stopped receiving message after sometime

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, spring-kafka

The kafka consumer stopped receiving messages after sometime, in other words the consumer started consuming messages for a day or two and its getting lost messages from one partition eventually stopped receiving messages from the whole topic, here is my consumer code and config

```
public class Listener implements AcknowledgingMessageListener<String, Request> {
@KafkaListener(topics = "topicname", groupId = "groupid",containerFactory = "kafkaListenerContainerFactory")
    @Override
    public void onMessage(ConsumerRecord<String, request> consumerRecord, Acknowledgment acknowledgment) {
        acknowledgment.acknowledge();
        try {
            //process the message
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            //publish it to DLT topic
        }

    }
}
```

Config:

```
private void setConsumerConfigs(PropertyConfig propertyConfig, Map<String, Object> props) {
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, propertyConfig.getKafkaBootstrapServer());
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class);
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class);
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.ENABLE_AUTO_COMMIT_CONFIG, false);
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG, "latest");
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.MAX_POLL_INTERVAL_MS_CONFIG,60000); // set it to 5 mins to avoid calling poll timeout
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.MAX_POLL_RECORDS_CONFIG,150);
    }

@Bean(name = "kafkaListenerContainerFactory")
    public ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, Request> kafkaListenerContainerFactoryString(
            PropertyConfig propertyConfig) throws FileNotFoundException {
        ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, Request> factory = new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();
        factory.setConsumerFactory(consumerFactoryString(propertyConfig));
        factory.getContainerProperties().setAckMode(AckMode.MANUAL_IMMEDIATE);
        factory.getContainerProperties().setSyncCommits(false);
        factory.getContainerProperties().setConsumerRebalanceListener(new RebalanceListener());
        factory.getContainerProperties().setCommitLogLevel(LogIfLevelEnabled.Level.INFO);
        return factory;
    }
```

I am using spring-kafka  version of 2.8.11

Comment: Take a thread dump; in my experience 99.9999% of these are due to the container thread being "stuck" in user code someplace. If that doesn't help, try debug logging.

Comment: I restarted the consumer but still its not consuming messages, do you see any discrepancies at the config, especially in the commit and poll interval

Comment: As I said, enable DEBUG logging.

Comment: Also use `kafka-consumer-groups` CLI to see if there's zero lag in a partition. If so, your producer is the problem... You should also acknowledge the message after processing, assuming you don't want to skip any messages. I'd also recommend using Spring Kafka 3+